# Getting NaN if variable has null value

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, nan

Here, I am getting record through ajax and json.
I am getting value if the variable have.
But, If variable **"performance"** have null value, it shows `NaN`.
Instead of `NaN`, I want to print number value like, `00.00`.

Is that possible? If yes then how? 
Thank you.

My code,

```
function emp_month_perf(){

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>grade_tasks/emp_monthly_performance",
                data:'',
                type:"GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){

                    var total_month_earn = data.total_earn_point;
                    var total_month_point = data.total_point;
                    var performance;
                    var per_color;
                    //var radius = "20px";
                    //alert(total_point);
                    performance = (((total_month_earn)/(total_month_point))*100).toFixed(2);
                    if(performance>80)
                    {
                        per_color = "#33CF53";
                    }
                    else if(performance>=60 && performance<=80)
                    {
                        per_color = "#E0C533";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        per_color = "#E12827";
                    }
                    //document.getElementById("monthperformance").style.borderRadius = radius;
                    document.getElementById("monthperformance").style.backgroundColor = per_color;
                    $('#monthperformance').html(performance);
                },
                error:function (){}
                });
                }
               setInterval(emp_month_perf, 300000);
```

Comment: What variable is null?

Answer (score 3):

Use an OR operator to set the number to zero.

```
var total_month_earn = data.total_earn_point || 0;
var total_month_point = data.total_point || 0;
```

But now you can have 1/0 which would be infinity. :)

Other option is to Check for NaN and than set the value to zero.

```
var performance = (((total_month_earn)/(total_month_point))*100);
var formatted = isNaN(performance) ? "00.00" : performance.toString(2);
```

Comment: Thanks @epascarello: But this is not working for me. If the variable have null value, it should print by defaulf 00.00.

Comment: I am not sure how `performance` has a `null` value. It should be "NaN" or "#.##" or "Infinity"

Comment: In the second option, I have to set variable "formatted" in html response. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Fix is as below Replace

```
performance = (((total_month_earn)/(total_month_point))*100).toFixed(2);
```

With

```
try {
  performance = (((total_month_earn)/(total_month_point))*100).toFixed(2);
  performance=isNaN(performance) ? "00.00" : performance;
}
catch(err) {
  performance="00.00";
}
```