# Javascript variable values are automatially changed to NaN and my script fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following requirement in my project, after a page loads, I have to make an async call to a web service (using jquery) which takes takes around 1 to 5 seconds for execution. There is an next button in the same page, and when the user clicks the next button before this call is completed, page navigation should be kept on hold. BTW my project works on IE 8 version.

In the mean time there is also another third party calls happening in the same page. This is triggered in parallel to the above ajax call and waiting time for it is around 2 seconds.

So I wrote the logic in such a way that when user clicks on next button, it will first verify the 2 seconds wait time and then it waits for 5 seconds for the ajax call to complete. If the ajax call completes in less than 5 seconds (eg. 1 or 2 sec) then the remaining waiting time is skipped and user is navigated to next page.

Following is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var callStatus = "Pending";       // Initially ajax call status will be pending
    var holdNavigation = true;                      // Initially this will be true
    var debug = false;

    // Set debug value only if it is set int web.config
    <% #if DEBUG %>
    debug = true;
    <% #endif %>

    function CallAsyncMethod() {
        // Only make the call if the flag is set in page load
        if ($("#<%= hiddenMakeAsyncCall.ClientID %>").val() == "true") {
            Log("async call started.");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "WebService.asmx/DoSomething",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    Log("async call completed with status - " + response.d.Status);
                    callStatus = response.d.Status;
                    holdNavigation = false;
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    Log("async call failed.")
                    callStatus = "Error";
                    holdNavigation = false;
                    Log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            holdNavigation = false;
            callStatus = "NotRequired";
        }
    }

    var delayInterval = 500;
    var timeElapsed = 0;
    var simulateNextButtonClick = false;

    // Next button validation function
    function ValidateNextButtonClick() {
        if (!IsThirdPartyCallWaitingTimeCompleted() || (holdNavigation && !IsAsyncCallCompleted())) {
            if (timeElapsed == delayInterval * 10) {
                holdNavigation = false;
                Log("async call timed out.");
            }
            else {
                Log("Time elapsed after next button click is " + timeElapsed + " milliseconds.");
                timeElapsed += delayInterval;
                setTimeout(ValidateNextButtonClick, delayInterval);
                simulateNextButtonClick = true;
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (simulateNextButtonClick) {
            simulateNextButtonClick = false;
            Log("Simulating the next button click as it was cancelled previously.");
            $("#<%= nextButton.ClientID %>").click();
        }

        Log("Navigating to next page.");
        return true;
    }

    // Waiting time for third party call to complete is 2 seconds,
    // check whether 2 seconds is completed or not.
    function IsThirdPartyCallWaitingTimeCompleted() {
        var afterThirdPartyCallLoadedTime = (new Date().valueOf() - thirdPartyCallLoadedTime) / 1000;

        if (afterThirdPartyCallLoadedTime >= 2) {
            Log("Third party calls completed.");
            return true;
        }

        Log("Waiting for third party calls to complete.");
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the async call is pending or not
    function IsAsyncCallCompleted() {
        if (callStatus == "Pending") {
            Log("Waiting for async call to complete.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (callStatus == "NotRequired") {
            Log("async call is not required.");
            return true;
        }

        Log("async call completed.");
        return true;
    }

    // Logs the message into console if the debug flag is set to true
    function Log(message) {
        if (debug) {
            $('#log').append(message + "<br/>");
            //window.console.log(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Code

```
        </p>
        <asp:Button ID="nextButton" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="nextButton_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateNextButtonClick()" />
        <br />
        some third party calls happen here
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var thirdPartyCallLoadedTime = new Date().valueOf();
        </script>

        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenMakeAsyncCall" runat="server" Value="true" />
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CallAsyncMethod();
</script>
```

This code is working when i test in a new application, but its not working when I try in my project. It only works if I open the developer tool window in IE. When I debugged found that the variables for interval and timeelapsed are automatically changed to NaN

Please help me in solving this issue. Also let me know if there is a better way to implement what I did.

Comment: But I am not dividing anything by zero, all the values are in the page and its only multiplication that is happening in the script.

Comment: Try renaming the variables. They are global (stored in `window.delayInterval` and `window.timeElapsed`) and they may collide with other code (maybe the 3rd party one). Try names like `Harsha_delayInterval` to make them unique.

Comment: _undefined_ values are coerced to `NaN` when used in numeric context. Most likely some of your variables are undefined (uninitialized)

Comment: That's a good point, but I did try that, I prefixed my page name in front of these variables, but still the same problem.

Comment: Isn't there another way to detect the 3rd party call to finish? Waiting just 2 seconds and hoping it will finish is stupid. And instead of waiting 5 seconds for your call, you can simply call a method from the success and error handlers (and just setting `setTimeout(ajaxTimedOut, 5000)`).

Comment: If it only works when the developers tool is open, it might be a cache problem? Have you checked you source code in the browser is up to date?

Comment: @hindmost, I initialized my variables in the script, but something seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Radek, yes it looks stupid to wait 2 seconds, but i have to keep the user in the page for atleast 2 seconds there is no other option on that one and as i mentioned my call will not necessarily take 5 seconds, it can even be done in a second.

Comment: @gr3g I did try by clearing browser cache and tried in InPrivate as well.

Comment: @Harsha you say in the description that you have found that the 2 variables convert to NaN. When you have your breakpoint on the NaN variable, look to the call Stack (right of the console) in the source tab and click on the previous steps to see from where to problem might come

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting NaN if variable has null value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613774/getting-nan-if-variable-has-null-value)